# Why does my python give me the same output into a list no matter the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def choosecolours():
    colourletters = ["g","b","r","m","o","c"]
    colourlist = []
    while len(colourlist) < 3:
        colour = input("First choose a colour by entering the first letter of the colour you like: ")

    if colour in colourletters:
            colourlist.append(colour)
        else:
            print("Enter a valid letter!")
print(colourlist)
```

when i enter this code i always get the output ['r', 'b', 'm'], no matter what i input. I cannot see any reason this code does not work?

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem when putting it onto SO but the `else :` is indented incorrectly.

Comment: are you sure that you inserted your code as you run it?

Comment: your code doesnt look properly formatted to make sense. In its current form this is not valid python

Comment: after formatting the indentation in your code i am unable to replicate the behaviour you have an issue with. It seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `colourlist` defined globaly elsware in your code.
Since you are not returning `colourlist` then when you try and access it outside of the function it should come up as undefined unless you have it somewhere else. If so when you access it globaly you will just get a reference to the other global reference.

Running the above code as is gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'colourlist' is not defined
```

Try:

```py
def choosecolours():
    ...
    return colourlist

list = choosecolours()
print(list)
```

It is to do with the scope of variables. Variables defined localy are contained localy i.e using `var` in a function can not be accessed outside the function as that name is released at the end of the function.

Comment: try to avoid giving variables names that are already python builtins as you will overwrite the builtin.

Comment: fixed, thanks mate. still not sure why it didn't before i understand what you're saying but its referenced for the first time in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```py
def choosecolours():
    colourletters = ["g","b","r","m","o","c"]
    colourlist = list()
    while len(colourlist) < 3:
        colour = input("First choose a colour by entering the first letter of the colour you like: ")
        if colour in colourletters:
            colourlist.append(colour)
        else:
            print("Enter a valid letter!")
    return colourlist

output = choosecolours()
print(output)
```

If you want to use a variable from outside function you give your variables pointer to that function as a parameter.

Comment: you dont return anything from teh function so `output` will always be `None`